# Image directories and cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, cx-freeze

So basically i want to convert a .py script into an executable file. The only problem is is that the setup.py file has to be in the same directory as the image and sound files, while my game file is in a directory above that with the setup.py.
How do i edit the setup file so that i dont have to go around and change all the code in my game file? If needed i'll edit the game file but preferably not.

```
from os import path

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')
snd_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'snd')

#ways i load in images:
background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 
"background.jpg")).convert()

alien_images = []
alien_list = ['alien1.png', 'alien2.png']
for img in alien_list:
    alien_images.append(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 
                                                    img)).convert())`
```

This is the setup file i have now. Apart from it being unable to find the images and sounds of course, it is error free.

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Shmup.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Shoot 'm up!",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                         "include_files": ["alien1.png", "alien2.png",
                                            "background.jpg", "laser1.png",
                                            "powerUp.png", "shield.png",
                                            "regularExplosion00.png", 
                                            "regularExplosion01.png",
                                            "regularExplosion02.png", 
                                            "regularExplosion03.png",
                                            "regularExplosion04.png", 
                                            "regularExplosion05.png",
                                            "regularExplosion06.png", 
                                            "regularExplosion07.png",
                                            "regularExplosion07.png", 
                                            "regularExplosion08.png",
                                            "regularExplosion09.png", 
                                            "ship1.png",
                                            "sonicExplosion00.png", 
                                            "sonicExplosion01.png",
                                            "sonicExplosion02.png", 
                                            "sonicExplosion03.png",
                                            "sonicExplosion04.png", 
                                            "sonicExplosion05.png",
                                            "sonicExplosion06.png", 
                                            "sonicExplosion07.png",
                                            "sonicExplosion08.png", 
                                            "sonicExplosion09.png",
                                            "Expl.wav", "Expl2.wav", 
                                            "Music.ogg", "Pew.wav",
                                            "Powerup.wav", "Rumble.ogg"]}},
    executables = executables
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a relative directory in your "include_files" directive. Something like this:

`include_files = [("game_assets", "assets")]`

That will copy all of the files in the directory "game_assets" to a target directory "assets". You can use whatever you wish for the names, of course!